# SVG path error: <path> attribute d: Expected number

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm using a layout library which is producing some paths for me that I'm trying to transform into SVG paths. Most paths seem fine, but a few give errors and I've not been able to figure out why.

Example:

```
<path d=" M0 0 C  0 90,  56 90,  56 279,  163 279, 163 309 z"></path>
```

I have a JSFiddle that you can run and see the error in the console [here](https://jsfiddle.net/teserract101/8uhdmjvr/).

The error I get is:

> Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "…63 279, 163 309 z".

Comment: After a `C` command, there need to be a multiple of 3 coordinate pairs (rwo control points and a new current point). The above path with 5 coordinate pairs is missing a final one.

Comment: You would need one more pair of coords. Since the last command is a z (close path) you can add the coords of the first move to (M) command. Please try this: ` <path d="M0,0 C0,90  56,90  56,279  163,279 163,309 0,0"></path>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to make sure path data is consistent with SVG's standard:
https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#DAttribute

If you are using comma to separate values, then it should be used consistently:

```
"M0,0 C0,90 56,90 56,279 163,279 163,309 z"
```

If not using comma:

```
"M 0 0 C 0 90 56 90 56 279 163 279 163 309 z"
```

UPDATE: ccprog is correct int he comments that consistency is not a requirement. So its more of a convenience / practice to keep things consistent.

Now the issue with the error that you observe in the console is due to the rule how path letters can be eliminated:

> The command letter can be eliminated on subsequent commands if the
> same command is used multiple times in a row (e.g., you can drop the
> second "L" in "M 100 200 L 200 100 L -100 -200" and use "M 100 200 L
> 200 100 -100 -200" instead).

Basically in your case browser believes you are using Cubic Bezier curves in succession:

> "M0,0 C0,90 56,90 56,279 C163,279 163,309 z"

So it interprets "z" as the last coordinate it expects for the Cubic Bezier curve.

You can eliminate error by adding a missing point or using different command explicitly.

Comment: You're right, my data was inconsistent. I tried it the way you suggested but I still get the same error.

Comment: I followed the provided link (JSfiddle) and it shows no errors. Can you post a link to the issue? which browser are you using?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/teserract101/8uhdmjvr/4/ -> I see issues in this in the chrome developer console. You don't see anything?

Comment: oh now I see. OK I know whats happening. Let me update the answer.

Comment: @shashankchaudhry let me now if this clarifies the issue for you.

Comment: Consistency in the use of commas and whitespace is not needed within path commands. The [grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataBNF) allows for all possible combinations, as long as numbers are clearly discernable by a greedy parser.

Comment: appreciate comment;) and agree.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This was indeed the issue.